# Streaming Audio Using Fetch

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming

I'm working on a side project that is a music app. This requires me to play large files. I've figured out that there are a few solutions. One is to download the music to local storage and use that whenever it is available. I can also stream music over the network. I have been unsuccessful as it relates to the latter.

My question is, how do I play from a audio from a stream?

This is the code I have so far:

```js
fetch(audio)
  .then((res) => {
    const reader = res.body.getReader()

    const audioObj = new Audio()

    reader.read().then(function processAudio({ done, value }) {
      if (done) {
        console.log("You got all the data")
        return
      }

      /// DO SOMETHING WITH VALUE

      return reader.read().then(processAudio)
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Something went wrong ${err}`)
  })
```

I have tried looking at other APIs within the browser, eg. [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/MediaStream)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WebAudio API that might be useful. It appears to give you exactly what you need.

[Web Audo API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Comment: I'm actually trying to use it right now. I'm still facing the same issue - instead of the song playing while it's being loaded, it plays only when it has finished loading. This makes for a bad UX